# Reading the number of characters in a string in C

Tags: c, string, count, pipe, fork

I want to use pipes to read a string in child process and send it to the parent, then count the number of characters in the string and display the number. The program runs only until I input a string. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h> 

#define SIZE 1024


int main()

{

int i,n,x;
char msg[SIZE];  
char str[SIZE]; 



int p3[2];

pipe(p3);

int pid=fork();


if(pid==0){


close(p3[0]); //closing read end

printf("Enter a string\n");
fgets(msg,SIZE,stdin);

write(p3[1],msg,sizeof(msg)); //writting into pipe
close(p3[1]); //closing write end


}

else {

close(p3[1]); //close write end

read(p3[0], str, sizeof(str)); 

int c = 0;

while (str[c] != "Done")
   {
 for(i=0; i<sizeof(str);i++){
      if (str[c] >= 'a' && str[c] <= 'z') {
          c++;
}
   }
}

printf("%d letters\n", c); 
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might invite more answers if you made your code readable with proper indentation.

Comment: `while (str[c] != "Done")` you are comparing a single character to a string constant (actually a pointer) you meed strcmp() or strncmp() (or memcmp()) here.

Answer (score 2):

Use strlen to determine the length of the string then use for loop to iterate upto the length, something like below:

```
    if (strncmp(str, "Done", 4) == 0)
        exit(0);

   int len = strlen(str);

    for (l = 0; l < len; l++)
    {
        if (str[l] >= 'a' && str[l] <= 'z') 
        {
            c++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d letters\n", c); 
    close(p3[0]); //close write end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `strlen()` to determine the length of any null-terminated string;
2. In `while (str[c] != "Done")` you're comparing a char to a string literal. You should use `strcmp()` or `strncmp()` to compare strings;
3. The inner-loop (`for(i=0; i<sizeof(str);i++) {...}`) is using `str[c]`, but I believe you want `str[i]`, besides, the loop is not counting (`c++`) when the char is not in the interval `[a,z]`, therefore your outer-loop may never end;
4. You really don't need nested loops. Try something like:

```
const char *ptr = str;
size_t index = 0; // An index to access str - just to help you.

// Iterate over ptr, one character at a time, until we find the null terminator.
while (*ptr != '\0') {
    // Read 4 chars from ptr and check if it's "Done"
    if (strncmp(ptr, "Done", 4) == 0)
        break;

    // Do something here. For example:
    // if (str[index] >= 'a' && str[index] <= 'z')
    //     lowercase_counter++;
    // if (str[index] >= 'A' && str[index] <= 'Z')
    //     uppercase_counter++;
    // if (str[index] >= '0' && str[index] <= '9')
    //     number_counter++;
    // NOTE: str[index] is equivalent to *ptr, thus you can use one or another.

    ptr++;
    index++;
}
```

Be sure to not increment `ptr` elsewhere - the idea is for each loop iteration to check a single character - you can still read ahead using `strcmp` or whatever, like we did for "Done". If you do that, also take care to not access `ptr` beyond the `str` boundaries.

Comment: this gives me a wrong number of letters:                                                             `int c = 0;


if(str == "Done"){
exit(1);
}

else{
 for(i=0; i<sizeof(str);i++){
      if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') 
         { c++;}

   }
printf("%d letters\n", c);
}
`

Comment: `if(str == "Done")` - You cannot compare strings using `==`. You need `strcmp` or `strncmp`! I already did that for you in the code I posted above. And you're counting only lowercase letters. Is that what you want? Besides that, you MUST stop the loop when you find a null terminator (`'\0'`).

Comment: ok i changed it to  `if(strcmp("Done",str) == 0){
exit(1);
}` yes i am only counting lowercase letters

Comment: Also add `if (str[i] == '\0') break;` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: but the result is still incorrect. How can i fix that? It counting like 52 extra characters

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like except for the part you pasted in the comments - and that should work fine by itself. But if you're using my code above and your code inside the loop I wrote, then the code is iterating multiple times over the same string - you need only 1 loop.